# Stop Kafka Consumer Dynamically

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using Spring boot application with Spring Kafka. The application is deployed in two servers. I have a Kafka Consumer listening to a particular topic. I have set the concurrency of consumer to be 6. So there are 3 consumers created in each server listening to the topic.

My requirement is to stop all the kafka consumer on any one server. So the end result is that there will be only 3 Kafka consumer remaining started and other 3 is stopped.
I have gone through the answers where it stops container and as a result all the consumers are stopped. But I want to stop consumers based on server.

Comment: What you are suggesting makes no sense. There is no interaction between instances; if you stop one container, only that one will stop, the partitions will be reassigned to the other instance. If the concurrency is 6 and you only have 6 partitions then all 6 partitions might be assigned to one instance. `concurrency*instances` must be less than or equal to the number of partitions. Otherwise you will have idle consumers with no partitions assigned.

Comment: @GaryRussell I have concurrency set as 3 .Correct me in that case if application is deployed in two instances, then each instance will be assigned three partition correct?And how to get container details per instance using Java?

Comment: For 6 partitions, that's not guaranteed. You could end up with 6+0, or 5+1,or 4+2, depending on the PartitionAssignor that's been configured... You can see Spring-kafka docs for `onPartitionsAssigned` callback function to check